# Apple's iAd's sample code not working as expected

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, iad

I am trying to implement iAd's in my app and written all the required code for this... But for reasons unknown to me and my pals, my code is not working and i am not able to see the iAd's in my app. Even sample code from apples regarding iAd's is not working on my mac. The same code worked absolutely fine when ran on another system from another location. me and my pals are scratching our heads due to this from the past 3 days. I am posting two screenshots of the same code ran from two different locations and machines.... i am using X-code version 3.2.5, SDK version 4.2, Mac version 10.6.

All the inputs of any kind are appreciated.... [image: output from other location and system]

[image]

[image: sdk information]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When testing iAd on your iPhone simulator you will obtain a couple of positive and negative feedbacks for each iAd request. This is made to give you the possibility to test what will happen when you receive an ad, and when you do not receive it.

Generally, if you launch the application a couple of times, you should be able to see the ads appear almost once.

Otherwise, to better investigate the problem, you should post some example code from your app, to understand how you implemented the delegate methods to handle iAd events.

Comment: Hi marzapower.... Thanx 4 the answer... Like i mentioned in my question above, this is the sample code that i'v borrowed from apple's developer website. I have been trying to implement at least this code from past 3 days, but just ran out of luck i guess....

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you implemented to 1) create the ADBannerView and 2) to handle the callbacks?

Comment: I have not written any new code marzapower.. I have downloaded the sample code from developer.apple.com and ran the same code on my machine... This is the link to the code http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iAdInterstitialSuite/Introduction/Intro.html. this is the 2nd link...

Comment: It could be a problem with you Internet connection, I think. I can't see any other problems.

Comment: ya... even i thought of the same thing.... can u please tell me what are the settings or requirements that i need for the iAd's to work.... This would be of great help